# How do I structure this in Angular: Multiple components requesting same data from HTTP

Tags: angular, http

Let's say I'm building a shopping app and one of the features it has is to give users the ability to browse a category of items. While browsing the items, the user can store the items into their own lists (like Amazon's wish list feature). Therefore, I have a component called `item` which shows an item to the user.

The item component allows the user to click a `+` icon in it which will show the user's their lists. Then the user can select a list to add the item to. Kind of like what YouTube did here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jMKz.png.

I also plan to have a list page, where a user can browse the items of a specific list they made. The list page would have a lot of `item` components.

The problem is that while there are many `item` components displayed on the page, **they all need to know the lists that the user has created**, and their lists are retrieved from a web server (from a database).

So how would I do this? I could have all of them make an HTTP request, but that would execute an HTTP request for each item on the page, only to get the same data. I could pass this responsibility to a parent component, but sometimes the `item` components would be by itself with no parent to get the lists from.

Answer (score 0):

You can have component structure like below and use the angular store to manage the state of the data which can be shared accross components.

- Parent ItemList Component: Which will have one http call to fetch the list of items and save to the store.
- Child Item Component: can retrieve the list from the store on the click of add event and if store is empty call the http to retrieve the list and save it to store for any subsequent calls.

  - More details about the store can be found at:
    https://github.com/ngrx/platform
  - Example of a book collection application from ngrx team can be found here:
    https://stackblitz.com/github/ngrx/platform/?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Freducers%2Flayout.ts

Answer (score 0):

I am also a building a large scale shopping cart and this is how I implemented my application. I have a user model like so in mongodB:

```
name
item[]
order[]
savedForLater[]
....
```

The user is allowed to add items to the cart without signing on using MongoStore/session. The user can also save items for later in session.  I could have used localStorage but this is what I learned in AngularJs. When the user is signed on, the items and saveForLater are saved in user's items and savedForLater in dB. Below is my partial code to for SavedItemForLater:

```
savedForLaterUserLoggedIn(itemObj: Item){
  this._itemLaterService.addItemLater(itemObj).subscribe(
    itemLater =>{
      this._itemLaterService.getItemsLaterUser().subscribe(
        items => {
              if(items.length == 0) {
                this._itemLaterService.isLaterSession = false;
                this.isLaterSession = false;
                return;
              }                 
              this.laterSessionItems = items;
              this._itemLaterService.isLaterSession = true;
              this.isLaterSession = true;        
              let itemId = itemObj.itemId; 
              this.deleteItem(itemId); // delete item from user         
          this.leftButton = 'none';
          this.getSaveLaterResponsive();                    
        },
        error=>{ console.log('get items later user logged in 
               error!'); 
      });
  },
  error=> { console.log('add item later user logged n error!'); }
  ); 
}
```

The attached images should give you a better explanation. Note. The item on the right has QTY: 2. Let me know if you need more information.[image]